# Creating a Sublime Text plugin to show a window with JSON data

Tags: python, json, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

So I'm trying to create a plugin for Sublime Text, that allows me to look at JSON data in a "tree" structure, where things can be expanded and minimized.  I managed to implement this using the menus, but it looks very sloppy.  Is there a way to create like an "alternate window" within Sublime Text to be able to do this sort of thing?  It would also be great if I can create it so that some action occurs when something in the tree is clicked.

Comment: If you want to create a graphical tree view, I doubt that it's possible. After all Sublime Text is a *text* editor.

Comment: What's wrong with just formatting the JSON properly and using the JSON syntax? Different levels can be folded using Sublime's built-in functionality. You can use Sublime's [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html) to specify Regions and attach an action to when `view.sel()` is in a certain Region.